# PolylinesOprtions DirectionRender react-google-maps/api

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, frontend, react-google-maps

I try to change marker on a DirectionRender from react-google-maps/api.
I already change de polyline color but i dont make change de marker A and B, my code.

```
<DirectionsRenderer
      getIcon={(icon) => console.log("icon render", icon)}
      options={{
        directions: response,
              polylineOptions: {
           strokeColor: "#c23531",
          icons: [{
            icon:{
              path:{to},
              strokeOpacity: 1
            },
            offset:'50%'
          },{
            icon:{
              path:{fromm},
              strokeOpacity: 1
            },
            offset:'50%'
          }],
        },
      }}
/>
```

Comment: Yes the things is, that change both marker, I want to change A and B marker

Answer (score 1):

The [DirectionsRenderer](https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#directionsrenderer) of [@react-google-maps/api library](https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/) doesn't have a `getIcon` prop name just like you have in your code. To change the icon of the markers in the DirectionsRenderer, you need to use the `options` which has the properties of [google.maps.DirectionsRendererOptions interface](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#DirectionsRendererOptions).

In there, you can see a `markerOptions` props name which uses the [google.maps.MarkerOptions interface](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerOptions) that have the `icon` properties.

Here's a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/directionsservice-markericons-ueur7r?file=Map.js) *(put your API key on the index.js file of the code sample to make it work)* and code snippet how to use the `options` properties to change the icon:

```
<DirectionsRenderer
              directions={this.state.directions}
              options={{
                markerOptions: {
                  icon:
                    'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'
                }
              }}
            />
```